# Filter option is not working React Data Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

As React Data Grid had issues with server side rendering, it was giving an error "self is not defined" when I was doing the bundling of files. Inorder to fix that I used the following piece of code in my module which fixed it.

`var ExecutionEnvironment = require('exenv');
if (ExecutionEnvironment.canUseDOM) {
  var ReactDataGrid = require('react-data-grid');
  var {Toolbar, Filters: {NumericFilter, AutoCompleteFilter, MultiSelectFilter, SingleSelectFilter}, Data: {Selectors}} = require('react-data-grid-addons');
}`

The following above piece of code however fixed the "self is not defined issue". However, it is causing the filter feature not to work. I am facing the following warning alone in console "getDefaultProps is only used on classic React.createClass definitions. Use a static property named `defaultProps` instead." for filter not working.  The filter row appears to be blurred as shown in the image [image]

Answer (score 0):

`defaultProps` replaced the `getDefaultProps` method in React, to declare defaultProps use

```
className.defaultProps = {
    propName: propValue,
    anotherName: anotherValue
}
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, The warning come as a result the package react-data-grid use the older of way defined i.e. getDefaultProps . Could someone help in fixing this gilter being blurred issue. I am not sure why this is caused.